# Fann library - possibility to switch off bias neurons

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, fann

I would like to ask whether there is possibility to gracefully switch off bias neurons from neural network in fann library? I have not noticed any function to  add/delete connection between neurons in fann documentation. The solution - setting after every training epoch 0 weights for bias neurons is pretty bad for me.

Question: is there any possibility to simulate activation_level = a_1 * x_1 + ... a_n * x_n not 
activation_level = a_1 * x_1 + ... a_n * x_n + bias?

Network created by fann_create_standard_array.

Official documentation lacks in these details, official forum also:
http://leenissen.dk/fann/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=851

No function like fann_set_connection_array
http://leenissen.dk/fann/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=570

Only for adding connections in fann_cascade found example:
http://leenissen.dk/fann/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=388

fann_cascade is not for me, because I need fixed network layout not growing during training.